# Pass a passed binding (@Binding)

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

If I pass a binding to another view can that 2nd view then pass the binding on and have the third view change the values in the first view or can this cause unexpected behavior?

For instance, if I have

```
struct FirstView: View {
  @State var input: String = ""

  var body: some View {
    Form {
      CustomTextField("Placeholder", $input)
    }
  }

}

struct CustomTextField: View {
  @Binding var text: String

  var body: some View {
    ThirdView(text: $text)
  }

}

struct ThirdView: View {
  @Binding var text: String

  var body: some View {
    TextField("Result", $text)
  }

}
```

I know the above is nonsensical - I'm only using it for demonstration purposes - but would the `ThirdView` properly update the state of the first?

I have had instances where it works fine and others where it doesn't but can't really find much of an explanation.

Comment: If you want to pass data between multiple views, why don't you use an `@EnvironmentObject`?

Comment: Because an `EnvironmentObject` is shared among all views. Im looking to encapsulate the binding. For instance, let's say in the form I have 10 `CustomTextFields` with 10 `@State vars` for each field. With a binding each `TextField` manages its own instance, which allows me to add or remove fields whereas an EnvironmentObject will give eacb `CustomTextField` access to all the other fields.

Comment: I had to do this technique, and it works for me. Except my only difference was the top ```@State``` I changed to ```@Binding```

Answer (score 0):

> If I pass a binding to another view can that 2nd view then pass the binding on and have the third view change the values in the first view or can this cause unexpected behavior?

By my observation there are following variants:

1) If those views live in one view hierarchy (or one in another) then such combination work

2) If those views are in different view hierarchies (or views are replaced, eg. by navigation) then binding works only on one level, but deeper transfer has unexpected behavior (most usual defect is that intermediate views are not updated).

Code in question works (tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4), because fits variant 1.

Comment: I have noticed today an issue that is worth mentioning here. If the third view is not a binding and is instead a let constant, then passing it down does not include any changes made along the way.

Comment: The only difference is that the type wasn't String. Instead it was a struct that had a bool property on it and the property wasn't updating.